# How to incorporate Multiple languages in a single os?

Tags: c#, vb.net, assembly, operating-system, kernel

I have a doubt about incorporating multiple languages into a single Operating System. For example : Windows 10 is build of C and Assembly in its core, which can be standalone or inline programs. What about the XML, C#, VB languages that is used in the OS. XML is used almost in all metro applications. How can a Kernel be the base for all such different languages? Will a OS has multiple compilers?

Comment: When you say, "How can a Kernel be the base for all such languages" are you just referring to all the compilers that OS Supports? This question makes little sense. Perhaps you should check out OSDev for in depth descriptions: http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page

Comment: No, what I mean is OS supports multiple languages without using any Third-Party compilers. How does it support? For example : In windows when you save a file as (.vbs), Its VBScript file and it executes. Similarily a batch file can be run on windows, again powershell commands and so on...

Comment: It doesn't. VBScript is interpreted by cscript.exe and so on. Or maybe it does, if you consider that interpreter part of the OS. Either way the kernel has nothing to do with it.

Comment: These are the same as those 'third-party' compilers. They are just written on the OS core Take Windows for example. a Compiler is written in C (Possibly) in order to compile powershell/vbscript/whatever. and are part of the OS

Comment: As @Harold says. Its merely a compiler coded and bundled with the OS

Comment: Also, See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingCompilers. This is an example of how you can add more Compilers to Ubuntu

Comment: In the olde days of VMS, the OS supported vendor compilers for numerous compiled languages including Ada, BASIC, Bliss, C, C++, Cobol, Dibol, FORTRAN, Lisp, Pascal, PL-I--and I am sure that I left some off.

Answer (score 2):

you confusion lies in the missing link of binaries supported by OS. It is not about languages which a OS can support or not but it is about binaries or executables which a OS supports. You can use C on both windows and Linux. it is compiler duty to produce binary(executable) compatible with underlying OS. 
Kernel can run some specific binaries or single binary which are produced by compilers.

> Will a OS has multiple compilers?

makes little sense instead you can say A OS support multiple compilers. A compiler is just another software with uniqueness of same dilemma: whether egg/chicken came into existence before chicken/egg. In order to know how different binaries are supported on same OS, you need to know about interpreters. But with out going into details about ABI and binary formats, you can say, OS supports comilers which produce executables which are runnable in the OS

A note for reminder: kernel is just set of functions/services to control the resources of the system